# Hide the child element of a div on hover

Tags: css, parent-child

Is there a way to make this work. I want to hover over the outer `div` and hide a child element without using javascript. Is something like this possible?

```
.fullwrap:nth-child(1):hover { 
    display: none; 
}
```

Comment: provide your html code also

Comment: It is technically possible, yes. Could you provide a jsFiddle or your HTML?

It terms of you hiding it, do you want to preserve the space where it was? Or act as if the element was never there? `visibility: hidden` will hide it

Comment: [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P4u5e/)

Comment: Thanks This is an awesome visual!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To hide a child element you need an structure like this:

```
#parent:hover .yourchild {
   display:none;
}
```

Where `#parent` is your outer `div` and has the `:hover` action, then you just match the child element to make it hide.

In this case I guess you have some structure like this:

```
<div class="fullwrap">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
</div>
```

Then to hide a child you can do some like this:

```
.fullwrap:hover :nth-child(1) { 
  display: none; 
}
```

Check this Demo http://jsfiddle.net/55TWN/