# How to change individual mouseover and mouseout events in *ngFor?

Tags: angular

I need to change the contents of one block when hover the mouse. all blocks are changing now

```js
@Component({
   selector: 'app-main',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
   public isChangedBlock = false;
   public itemPrefix: Array<string> = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split('');
    constructor() {}
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let item  of items; let i = index"
     (mouseover)="isChangedBlock = true"
     (mouseout)="isChangedBlock = false">
   <span [hidden]="isChangedBlock">text {{itemPrefix[i]}}</span>
   <span [hidden]="!isChangedBlock">icon</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You should do that with css

Comment: @ritaj, how? can you give an example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21555519/hide-the-child-element-of-a-div-on-hover

Comment: @DaniR Why would you set any variables for on hover? There is `:hover` pseudo class in css used literally for what.

Comment: So you say every mouse interaction is only for setting some styles?

Answer (score 3):

Use a different boolean for each block, the easiest way is to have a key/value object with key your index and value your boolean (or use an array, but in that case you have to handle its initialisation):

```js
@Component({
   selector: 'app-main',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
   public isChangedBlock = {};
   public itemPrefix: Array<string> = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split('');
    constructor() {}
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let item  of items; let i = index"
     (mouseover)="isChangedBlock[i] = true"
     (mouseout)="isChangedBlock[i] = false">
   <span [hidden]="isChangedBlock[i]">text {{itemPrefix[i]}}</span>
   <span [hidden]="!isChangedBlock[i]">icon</span>
</div>
```

Comment: A better approach is to outsource this to a component, which can decide by it's on what to do. Or wrap the display-logic in another div.

Comment: For something as simple as that? I'm not sure, but yeah if you want a more complex interaction or if you use it somewhere else as well it's better to create a component, but I was just trying to unblock new_user503 anyway, not write his whole code for him

Answer (score 0):

Do Like as 

`<div *ngFor="let item  of items; let i = index" (mouseover)="isChangedBlock = i" (mouseout)="isChangedBlock = -1">
      <span [hidden]="!(isChangedBlock === i)"> text {{itemPrefix[i]}}</span>
      <span [hidden]="!(isChangedBlock !== i)">icon</span>
    </div>`